# Is it important to delete deleted from code timers from jboss_ejb_timer. EJB3. POSTGRES

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee-7, ejb-3.2

I removed timer from code, but after app started, the timer is still exists in jboss_ejb_timer. It does not start, but maybe it is important to delete it from jboss_ejb_timer too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved
table is not self-clearable
you should delete rows for deleted timers if you dont want to see exeptions about not founding bean for timer execution